# In PostgreSQL how can an array column be filtered and searched for unique values only?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.5

I'm trying to compare values in a history table populated by update trigger to see if certain columns in the old and new values of the JSON fields are equal and if all are equal then be able to create a case when query. Here's what I'm trying to do:

**SQL**

```
create table history
(
    id           serial not null,
    ts           timestamp default now(),
    table_schema text,
    table_name   text,
    operation    text,
    updated_by   text      default CURRENT_USER,
    new          json,
    old          json
);


With t AS (
select id,
       old->>'field1' = new->>'field1' as isMatchField1,
       old->>'field2' = new->>'field2' as isMatchField2,
       old->>'field3' = new->>'field3' as isMatchField3,
       old->>'field4' = new->>'field4' as isMatchField4
from history)

select id, array [isMatchField1, isMatchField2, isMatchField3, isMatchField4] from t
```

**OUTPUT**

1, {true, true, false, null}

How do filter out all nulls from the array and do a case when query to see if only true valuesexists. basically I want to do something like:

```
select id, 
case when array field is only true and null then 'no changes made'
else
  'changes made'
end as updated
from t
```

Comment: I guess I can take the data returned by the query and do this task Python but if it can be done all in PostgreSQL it'll be great!

Comment: Not sure about 9.2 or 9.5 versions. Try `select id, case when old::jsonb = new::jsonb then 'no changes made' else 'changes made' end as updated from history;` At least it works in 11 version.

Comment: And for array try `case when coalesce(true = all(<your array here>), true) then 'changed' else 'not changed' end`